# Convert integer to string Jinja

Tags: python, jinja2, nunjucks

I have an integer

```
{% set curYear = 2013 %}
```

In `{% if %}` statement I have to compare it with some string. I can't set `curYear` to string at the beginning because I have to decrement it in loop.

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 340, accepted):

I found the answer.

Cast integer to string:

```
myOldIntValue|string
```

Cast string to integer:

```
myOldStrValue|int
```

Comment: What page did you find that on?

Comment: @Sergio heh, I don't remember, that was several years ago :)

Comment: Confirmed to work on nunjucks (which is based on jinja) on (email) HTML builds. That's how to convert numeric string values to integers. Btw, in my case I've got integers as strings coming from JSON content files: `"hero_title_img_w": "111"` and `"hero_title_img2_w": "222"`. Then I'm adding them in .NJK file: `{{ hero_title_img_w|int + hero_title_img2_w|int }}` to use as image's `width` attribute. Hope it helps somebody one day.

Comment: For those wanting the docs, this is a builtin filter: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters

Answer (score 9):

The OP needed to cast as string outside the `{% set ... %}`.
But if that not your case you can do:

```py
{% set curYear = 2013 | string() %}
```

Note that you need the parenthesis on that jinja filter.

If you're concatenating 2 variables, you can also use the `~` [custom operator](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#other-operators).

Answer (score 2):

Formatting `someInt` as a string can be achieved through:

```
'{0:d}'.format(someInt)
```

This syntax come from ansible, that also uses *Python* and *Jinja*. behind the scene.

Comment: The question was for Jinja2, there is no mention of Ansible in the question.

Comment: @GinoMempin while this is true ansible is implemented in Python and uses jinja. I just tested and this trick works!