# jinja2 string comparison when one value is null?

Tags: jinja2

Jinja2 template code:

```
{% if u.user_name == u.user_email %}
 {{ u.user_email }}
{% else %}
 {{ u.user_name }}<br />
 {{ u.user_email }}
{% endif %}
```

Usually the data source sets the user_name field to user_email if there is no separate name. However, sometimes there is nothing defined for the user_name field at all.

The problem is that in the Jinja2 code above, if the user_name field is undefined / null, the test above evaluates to false and both lines get spit out — one of which is blank.

I'm not sure how to properly write this test syntax. I've read the documentation and have tried approaches like [Convert integer to string Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161093/convert-integer-to-string-jinja) and [compare two variables in jinja2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623768/compare-two-variables-in-jinja2-template/12629325#12629325). I guess I have a problem with data types, I'm just not sure how to write this syntax so that it works.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want is None... try this

```
{% if (u.user_name == None or u.user_name == '') and u.user_name == u.user_email %}
    {{ u.user_email }}
{% else %}
    {{ u.user_name }}<br />
    {{ u.user_email }}
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are these options for `u.username`:

- `u.user_name` is not defined
- `u.user_name` is `None`
- `u.user_name` is an empty string
- `u.user_name` is a non-empty string

```
{% if u.user_name is not defined or u.user_name == None  or u.user_name == '' or u.user_name == u.user_email %}
    {{ u.user_email }}
{% else %}
    {{ u.user_name }} <br />
    {{ u.user_email }}
{% endif %}
```

But a shorter solution is to use `default` filter:

```
{% if u.user_name | default(u.user_email, true) == u.user_email %}
    {{ u.user_email }}
{% else %}
    {{ u.user_name }} <br />
    {{ u.user_email }}
{% endif %}
```

If `u.user_name` is not defined, `default` filter returns its first argument (a default value), otherwise it returns `u.user_name`.

It is important to set the second argument of `default` to `true`. In that case `default` returns its first argument (the default value) for `u.user_name` defined as `None` or as an empty string.

docs:
[is](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#tests)
,
[defined](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-tests.defined)
,
[default](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default)